# Nuxt JS / Vue JS search filter not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've recently had some help building a search component for a properties website. The idea is I have a `/properties` page with a list of properties and a generic search component which is on every page with an action that points to `/properties` and a `GET` method.

An example search could be:

```
/properties/?search=Green%20Park&type=Apartment&type=Bungalow&bedrooms=1&county=Blaenau%20Gwent
```

or...

```
/properties/?search=&type=Apartment&bedrooms=1&county=
```

I have some code which is meant to display filtered properties as a computed property. However, there seems to be something wrong inside the `else` statement and it's not returning anything. Here's my code:

```
computed: {
    filteredProperties: function () {
        let self = this
        let routeConstraints = ['search', 'type', 'bedrooms', 'county'].filter(function (val) {
            return self.$route.query[val] !== undefined
        })
        if (routeConstraints.length === 0) {
            return self.properties
        } else {
            return routeConstraints.reduce(function (acc, val) {
                return acc.filter(function (property) {
                    //basically I am checking if there is some value in the query parameter that matches properties.
                    return self.$route.query[val].some(function (item) {
                        //changed the matching condition to indexOf
                        return property[val].match(item).length > 0
                    })
                })
            }, self.properties)
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
self.$route.query[val].some is not a function
```

But it only errors when trying to use the search (see above example), and works fine if I'm not using the search and going directly to the properties page: `/properties`.

Type: could be a single type, or multiples.

Could anyone help me out and explain why it's giving me that error and how to resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: `self.$route.query[val]` returns a string value therefore you can't use `some` method, which is for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give, you're not passing an array of elements to the query. When each query param only has one value it is returned as a string. When it has more than one value e.g. `test=1&test=2`, it will return an array of strings.

I think what you are really looking to do is test if any query param matches as key. One way to do this is:

```
return Object.keys(self.$route.query).some(function (item) {
   return property[val].match(item).length > 0
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this wrong due to you didn't use the `ES6`, `self` not recognized in it, you can use `arrow function` instead,

```
computed: {
 filteredProperties() {
    let routeConstraints = ['search', 'type', 'bedrooms', 'county'].filter((val) => {
        return this.$route.query[val] !== undefined
    })
    if (routeConstraints.length === 0) {
        return this.properties
    } else {
        return routeConstraints.reduce((acc, val) => {
            return acc.filter((property) => {

                return this.$route.query[val].some((item)=> {
                    //changed the matching condition to indexOf
                    return property[val].match(item).length > 0
                })
            })
        }, this.properties)
    }
}
```

}